# Remote control or script Open Office to edit Word document from Python

Tags: python, replace, ms-word, libreoffice, openoffice-writer

I want to (preferably on Windows) start Open Office on a particular document, search for a fixed string and replace it with another string selected by my program.

How do I do that, from an external Python program?  OLE-something?  The native Python scripting solution?

<sup>(The document is in the Word 97-2003 format, but that is probably not relevant?)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say using the [Python-UNO bridge](http://udk.openoffice.org/python/python-bridge.html). Does this work for you?

```
import uno

ctx = uno.getComponentContext()
service_manager = ctx.getServiceManager() 
desktop = service_manager.createInstanceWithContext("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop", ctx)
document = desktop.loadComponentFromURL("file:///file.doc", "_blank", 0, ())

replace_desc = document.createReplaceDescriptor() 
replace_desc.setSearchString("text_to_replace") 

find_iter = document.findFirst(replace_desc)
while find_iter:
    find_iter.String = "replacement_text"
    find_iter = document.findNext(find_iter.End, replace_desc)
```

See the [XSearchable docs](http://api.openoffice.org/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/util/XSearchable.html) for details on searching. Also, make sure to have OpenOffice started with the following command line: `swriter "-accept=socket,host=localhost,port=2002;urp;"`.

Comment: Perhaps silly question, but when Python says, ImportError: no module uno, what am I doing wrong?  I have the standard Windows 2.7.2 Python installed.

Comment: It's an optional installable component for OpenOffice. See the [Introduction to Python on OOo](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Using_Python_on_Windows) page in OpenOffice's Wiki for installation details.

Comment: It runs now, but Python crashes: AppName: python.exe  AppVer: 0.0.0.0  ModName: vclmi.dll
ModVer: 3.4.302.500  Offset: 0000f13a

Comment: Are you using the python version that came with your OpenOffice installation? You can find it in "Program Files\OpenOffice3.x\program\python.exe".

Comment: I do (didn't at first, but found that it is the common thing to do)

Comment: I kind of doubt if the crash is related to this. Since there is no callstack, could you try to execute it line by line to see when it crashes? Seems to work fine here...

Comment: desktop = service_manager.createInstanceWithContext("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop", ctx)      <-- CRASHES ON THAT LINE

Comment: I will also try with OpenOffice instead of LibreOffice

Comment: Also crashes on the same line with OpenOffice

Comment: That's odd... could you try to run the example from the OpenOffice site itself? You can find it [here](http://udk.openoffice.org/python/python-bridge.html), try to run the one under the "Hello World" heading. I'd say that one should work without problems. Take care to use the topmost script (there are more "Hello world" examples on that page).

Comment: Ah, yes :). You have to have it running with `soffice "-accept=socket,host=localhost,port=2002;urp;"`... which I had by default. I added this to the answer.

Comment: Now I have the problem that whatever URL to load I use, it says the URL is invalid. I can change documents that were already opened though... ah, found it!  You need three slashes in the file:/// url. Thanks!