# How do you install or activate PyUno in LibreOffice?

Tags: python, libreoffice

How do you make Python (any Python) know about PyUno in LibreOffice?

When I do:

```
import uno
```

python says that it knows no module "uno". <sup>(This question came up re. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7783678/remote-control-or-script-open-office-to-edit-word-document-from-python).)</sup>

Comment: Please be more specific. How exactly did you install PyUno? And where? What's your `sys.path`? ...

Comment: related: [Python 2.7 with pyuno](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7763972)

Comment: See below [updating for 2014's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26630417/287948).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did:

inside the LibreOffice directory, there is a "program" directory with a python.exe, if I use that python (which is at version 2.6.1), I can import uno.

Comment: This is not a solution to your question. It's just a workaround.

Comment: It seems to me that using the built-in Python (as of LibreOffice4 and Python 3.3) is the only option here.  I have a very hard time finding out how I can install pyuno for my working Python environment...

Comment: @Clark, with some tweaking and working around the lack of other packages it worked for me too, it's just a bit of an annoyance to be constrained by that.  Having said that, I did not try to re-install the packages for LO-Python.  Would be nice if pyuno was provided as a PIP package...

Answer (score 4):

(UPDATING for 2014's)

Perhaps the most used UNO application is [document conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26630266/287948)... For this task, in nowadays, you not need UNO, you can use directly

```
libreoffice --convert-to
```

About UNO itself, see the new home page,  http://api.libreoffice.org/

A good example of using `python3-uno` (or `python-uno`) is the [Docvert conversor](https://github.com/holloway/docvert-python3/) ([Docvert for py2](https://github.com/holloway/docvert)).

Comment: This answer saved me a huge amount of time debugging endless issues with unoconv.

Answer (score 4):

For Debian, Ubuntu, and derivates:

```
sudo apt install libreoffice-script-provider-python
```

Answer (score 2):

As said in the response to your comment there: it's an optional installable component for OpenOffice. See the [Introduction to Python on OOo](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Using_Python_on_Windows) page in OpenOffice's Wiki for installation details

Answer (score 2):

> I am having the same issue with ubuntu 14.04 and python 2.7.6.
>
> But if you are using ubuntu 12.04, try using sudo apt-get install python-uno.

Comment: N!ce one, sir. Need to add that this days it's the package `libreoffice-script-provider-python`

Comment: For ubuntu 16.04 the required package is called python3-uno

Answer (score -1):

Try importing the libre office python extension.

> yum install libreoffice-pyuno