# How to access ODB files in Python 2.7

Tags: python, sqlite, python-2.7, hsqldb, libreoffice-base

I want to access an ODB file (made with LibreOffice Base) in Python and extract a table for further use. The ODB contains several tables, one relation design and several forms.

Is it possible to achieve this without using any SQL?

**Edit:** Since it seems overcomplicated to parse this format on my own, i'll consider using a proper HSQLDB engine.

What python module accesses via HSQL (like sqlite3 for SQLite does)?

Comment: If you don't use whatever form of SQL ODB would typically use, you're going to have to write your own parser for the format, which is going to be much more complicated than using a pre-built lib and learning how to write queries.

Comment: @Endophage: I see your point. Would [sqlite3](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html) work with ODB?

Comment: sqlite3 is its own database implementation. I believe (but I really can't say 100%) that it has no relation to ODB other than they are both databases... like Windows and Linux are both OSes.  You'll need to find a python lib specifically for ODB. The Python IRC channel is a good place to ask if nobody responds here.

Comment: If you just want to extract the table, might it not be simpler to export it as CSV in LibreOffice, then import it into something that has better Python support?

Comment: @Aya: it would be simpler, but i wanted to learn some SQL through this , e.g. use a client to make queries and so on

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can consider [Python Uno](http://www.openoffice.org/udk/python/python-bridge.html) API that comes with OpenOffice. There are several [Python examples](http://www.openoffice.org/udk/python/python-bridge.html#examples) to interact with the API, including one with the [sample database](http://www.openoffice.org/udk/python/samples/biblioaccess.py)

There is also this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784438/how-do-you-install-or-activate-pyuno-in-libreoffice) where it is explained how to use uno with LibreOffice.

Comment: +1 for pointing me to `PyUno`, it looks promising.  but concerning the [recent changes](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/ReleaseNotes/4.0#API_Changes) to LibreOffice's API, i'll have to see if it still works. also see this [blog](http://standardsandfreedom.net/index.php/2013/01/24/the-meaning-of-the-4-0/)

Comment: Yes, I have seen that: if you can afford it, stay on the previous major version up to the time pyuno is properly adapted to 4.0: they just don't seem to be ready to support pyuno+python3 on 4.0 right now...

Answer (score 1):

The default form of ODB file contains an HSQLDB database. You can extract this database then access it using HSQLDB software and any client that can connect to HSQLDB.

Instructions on how to extract the database can be found here:
http://programmaremobile.blogspot.co.uk/2009/01/java-and-openoffice-base-db-through.html