# Python Uno Not Found On Latest Open Office Installation

Tags: python, import, openoffice.org, uno, pyuno

Am now on the third Open Office 4 installation this week, direct from their site, ensuring 'Python Uno' is selected.  Whether running

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenOffice 4\program\python-core-2.7.6\bin\python.exe
```

directly or setting it as the Eclipse interpreter

```
import uno
```

keeps giving

```
no module named uno
```

Whether browsing or searching the OOo python-core2.7.6 folder in the OS, the module can't be found.  A 4 year old post had the same issue, and according to the docs it should be there.
[How do you install or activate PyUno in LibreOffice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784438/how-do-you-install-or-activate-pyuno-in-libreoffice)

Any thoughts?  Regards

Answer (score 0):

On Linux uno requires python3.
I see no reason why it would be any different on windows.
Try using python3

Comment: That's true for Linux.  On Windows it's python.exe whether the version is Python 2 or 3.

Comment: It might well be called python.exe but there must be one for python 2 and another for python 3, or we live in a mad mad world.

Comment: Well, they are at different locations.  Anyway it is different on Windows, because python comes bundled with the OpenOffice installer.  See [here](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=36370&p=166783) for a discussion.

Comment: @JimK Excellent, the more secondary documentation, in this case, the better!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenOffice 4\program\python-core-2.7.6`?  If not then you need to select the option to install the Python-UNO bridge when installing OpenOffice.

On Windows the paths need to be set up correctly.  Try this in powershell:

```
c:
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenOffice 4\program\"
./python
>>> import uno
```

If that works then you can modify the PYTHONPATH environment variable to include the OpenOffice program directory as well as the path to your script.